# Javascript "Error: null" with seemingly no cause on my end

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the error:

```
Error: null            https://replco.util.repl.co/devtools/devtools.js:74
  at t.formatMsg (https://replco.util.repl.co/devtools/devtools.js:74:4990)
  at new e (https://replco.util.repl.co/devtools/devtools.js:74:1632)
  at t.insertSync (https://replco.util.repl.co/devtools/devtools.js:97:17133)
  at https://replco.util.repl.co/devtools/devtools.js:97:18736
```

After a quick google search, I found nothing related to "Error: null" on its own, but it's possible it was drowned out by "TypeError: null".

Is it possible this is an error on my end or (what seems much more likely) is this a problem with replit, the service I'm hosting my code on?

If it is either, what would be / could be the way to resolve it? I'll edit this with my code if necessary, but it'd be a decent amount.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: A different JS/HTML/CSS program on the same hosting site did not produce the error...

Edit: Found the error. I was importing a .json file with [] as the outer container.